# Testing the convergence of the given integral and finding its value

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

@. Does the integral $$\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1+x\over 1-x}dx$$ exist ? If so, find it value.

I compared it with $1\over \sqrt {1-x}$ and showed that its convergent. To find its values  used the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ after conjugate multiplication of the integral which gives me the value of integral as $-\pi$. Is this correct ? Is there a direct/better way of finding the integral using the convergence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<a<1$ then $$\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}dx=\int_{-a}^a\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx+\int_{-a}^a\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx =2\arcsin(a)+0.$$  The last two integrals can be evaluated by finding the respective antiderivatives $\arcsin(x)$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, although the second integral is $0$ because the integrand is odd, so you don't need to find the antiderivative.  Letting $a\to 1-$ shows that the integral converges to $2\arcsin(1)=\pi$.

Comment: Right !! I made a mistake in calculation. One side questoin, what does it mean when an integral is not "convergent" ? Does it mean that if we integrate it,its value after putting limits of integral be $infty$ ?

Comment: @AmanMittal:  It depends on context, but in this context yes, it would be whether the positive function has a finite integral, as opposed to a $+\infty$ "integral".  The integral $\int_0^1\frac1{x}\,dx$ is divergent, but $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ is convergent in this sense.  However, $\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,dx$ is also not convergent, but does not have "value" $+\infty$ either.  (There can also be functions that aren't integrable because they are too discontinuous, so to speak.)

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is convergent to a real number $L$ if $\lim\limits_{c\to a+,d\to b-}\int_c^df(x)\,dx = L$.  This comes into question when $a=-\infty$ or $b=+\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to a+}|f(x)|=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to b-}|f(x)|=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=\cos2\theta$

$$\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}dx=\int_{\frac\pi2}^0\cot\theta(-2\sin2\theta)d\theta=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}4\cos^2\theta d\theta$$
$$=2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(1+\cos2\theta)d\theta=2\left(\theta+\frac{\sin2\theta}2\right)\big|_0^{\frac\pi2}=\pi+0-(0+0)=\pi$$

Comment: @JonasMeyer, is it OK?